# Rails 3 / Ruby: ActiveRecord Find method IN condition Array to Parameters single quote issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I created a method on a micropost model which takes an array of user_ids. In this method I use the following 'find' method to pull all posts for all of the users within the array.

```
find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id IN (?)", args.join(',')])
```

But when ActiveRecord generates the SQL for this query it surrounds the coma delimited list of Ids in single quotes. This causes the query to only pull posts for the first number within the single quotes instead of all the numbers.

```
SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE (user_id IN ('3,4,5')) ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC
```

The query should look like this to work correctly but I can't figure out how to get Ruby to convert the Array to a coma delimited list without the quotes, I know it has to be something simple and I am just missing it and can't find anything on Google that fixes this. All the posts I have found use the same .join(',') method to concert the Array.

```
SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE (user_id IN (3,4,5)) ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC
```

One more fact which migh assist you in figuring out my issue is the Array of ids which I am passing into the method is being built in the following manner. Not sure if this would affect things.

```
ids = Array.new
ids.push(current_user.id)
ids = ids + current_user.friends.map(&:id)
ids = ids + current_user.reverse_friends.map(&:id)
```

Thanks in advance to the one who can help me get back to work ;)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**Answer updated (twice) to reflect Rails 3+ ActiveRecord syntax**

### Rails 3+

You can use the following syntax:

```
Post.where(user_id: [1,2,3])
```

And thus:

```
Post.where(user_id: args)
```

#### Rails 3 or Rails 4 (Original)

For completeness, the Rails 3 syntax would be:

```
Post.where("user_id IN (?)", [1,2,3]).to_a
```

If args is an `Array`, then:

```
Post.where("user_id IN (?)", args).to_a
```

Or, if args is an array of strings:

```
Post.where("user_id IN (?)", args.map(&:to_i)).to_a
```

The `to_a` is optional, but will return the results as an array.  Hope this helps.

#### Rails 2

You should be able to simply pass in an array as the parameter, as follows:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id IN (?)", [1,2,3] ] )
```

Thus, if args is an array of ids, you should simply call:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id IN (?)", args ] )
```

In case you have an issues with types, you can do:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id IN (?)", args.map { |v| v.to_i } ] )
```

and this will ensure each item in the array is an Integer.

Comment: when using results = find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id IN (?)", args]) the SQL looks as follows SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` WHERE (user_id IN ('---\n- 3\n- 4\n- 5\n')) ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC

Comment: Try using my third query.  I think it'll help.

Comment: used the third query and I think it is moving us in the right direction. I then got the error 'undefined method `to_i' for [3, 4, 5]:Array' which lead me to output the array that I am passing in and the inspect on the array is as follows: [[3, 4, 5]]. This leads me to believe that the way I am trying to concatenate the arrays is actually creating an array of arrays rather than a single array. Can you take a look at that method and see if you can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As a quick mention: passing args[0] should work :)  To solve the deeper issue, how are you getting from **ids** to **args**.  You are somehow forming a new array in that process.  The **ids** array should be sound.

Comment: Yup, it was something really simple and easily overlooked. The method containing the Find query was accepting an *args parameter which I in turn was using as the passed in Array of ids. But of course it is an Array of Arrays. So I switched the method from accepting *args and just accepting an array of Ids. Total nub mistake. I really appreciate the help debugging my code, sometimes you can't see the forest through the trees ;)

Comment: Anytime.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 20):

In rails 3 and 4, you could also simply pass the array as an argument like so:

```
Post.where(:user_id => [1,2,3])
```

And that will give you the same result as

```
Post.where("user_id IN (?)", [1,2,3])
```

Comment: The first example is good for handling possible nil values as well. e.g. `Post.where(:user_id => [1,2,nil])`